Preserve line breaks with PostgreSQL COPY statement
I have a PostgreSQL statement inside a function which looks like this and puts some markdown content from the content column into a file:
LOOP
  EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (SELECT %L) TO ''%s''', _page.content, _directory || '/pages/' || _page.id || '.md');
END LOOP;

The column markdown content has line breaks, and looks like this when I inspect it with a normal SELECT statement inside psql:
-[ RECORD 1 ]+----------------------------------------------------------
content      | ## First heading\r                                       +
             | \r                                                       +
             | ### Second heading\r                                     +
             | \r                                                       +
             | Some random content                                      +

So in the outputted markdown file, I would expect this content:
## First heading

### Second heading

Some random content

But line breaks and carriage returns are just shown in their plain text forms, so it has this awkward look:
## First heading\r\n\r\n### Second heading\r\n\r\nSome random content

Is there any way to preserve the line breaks and get that previously shown wanted output when using the COPY command?

You can try (FORMAT 'csv'), but that will give you quoting characters.

Any idea how I could get rid of the quoting characters? @LaurenzAlbe

I would have told you if I knew a way.

I am not sure COPY in a LOOP for for single values is the optimal way ...
Be that as it may, to interpret Posix escape string syntax, prefix your string literal with E:
LOOP
  EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (SELECT E%L) TO ''%s''', _page.content, _directory || '/pages/' || _page.id || '.md');
END LOOP;

See:

Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL


This unfortunately does nothing, it stays with showing the literal linebreaks and carriage returns, only the solution of @Laurenz Albe worked, by using the CSV Format.
